# bootstrap-datetimepicker.js it doesn't work in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been testing some examples from this http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ with MVC 5. I'm install Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker/).

I had to add  this code in BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",//adding code
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

this is the code of my view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
}
```

However the web page load with some problem

the page should look like this

[image]

but it looks like this

[image]

I was seeing this forum http://forums.asp.net/t/1988610.aspx?Bootstrap+v3+DateTimePicker+in+MVC+5 and apparently there are problems with this.

Any ideas??????

Comment: Check your browser's debug console. Are there any 404s or errors logged?

Comment: @Jasen I check my browser's debug console and all right

Comment: I see this question [MVC4 Eonasdan Bootstrap 3 Date Time picker doesn´t open the picker screen][1] and the  answer of @Tieson_T it works for my


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644222/mvc4-eonasdan-bootstrap-3-date-time-picker-doesn%C2%B4t-open-the-picker-screen

Comment: I see this question  [MVC4 Eonasdan Bootstrap 3 Date Time picker doesn´t open the picker screen][1] and the  answer of @tieson-t it works for me


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644222/mvc4-eonasdan-bootstrap-3-date-time-picker-doesn%C2%B4t-open-the-picker-screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I solved my problem using  the answer of @tieson-t in the  question [MVC4 Eonasdan Bootstrap 3 Date Time picker doesn´t open the picker screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20645677/2399444).
See recommended page.

Comment: Thanks! The @Tieson's answer solved my issue.
The issue was the fact that I've mixed up the precedence of loading `jQuery` and  `$(function(){...});`

Answer (score 1):

My working example after some  hours :)
Style section ov page (I'm placing at head) :

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now scripts (Placing at foot):

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

}

Works for me

Answer (score 0):

I sure there is not conflict between MVC 5 and Bootstrap DatePicker. Maybe the problem is with a css
in your site. Did you added the css files for bootstrap and bootstrap-datepicker????

Comment: Yes I  added the css files for bootstrap and bootstrap-datepicker 'bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));'