# Bootstrap Date Time Picker not showing up in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

i am trying to use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker/) Date time Picker in MVC, its been hours but picker screen is not showing up, i also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644222/mvc4-eonasdan-bootstrap-3-date-time-picker-doesn%C2%B4t-open-the-picker-screen)

**BundelConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                                    "~/Scripts/moment.js",
                                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"              
                                    ));

// other bundles here

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                                   "~/Content/site.css",
                                   "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                                   "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"   
                ));

// other bundles here
```

**My View:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_Layout:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 @Styles.Render("~/css/boostrap.css")

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div>

// here other divs

   @RenderBody()


</div>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/boostrap.min.js"></script>

@section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

**Expected output**

http://jsfiddle.net/RR4hw/7/

i am not able to figure out what i am doing wrong ?, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Open your developer tools in your browser, go through your Sources and see if you can find all the source files you should have. If that proves unfruitful, check to see if there are any console errors.

Comment: hi, i went to inspect element --> Debugger --> Sources --> here, _bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js_ is grayed out, i guess the file is not loaded

Comment: That would explain it, sure. Can you edit your question to show your _Layout view please? I've assumed that you added the scripts to your view as demonstration but you're not using bundles correctly anyway I don't think.

Comment: i have added the layout, may be this would help to find whats wrong

Comment: You have this issue in all the browsers??? Bcoz, if u r using IE 8 there is some position issue. If this is issue is not on all browsers then it is a reference issue.

Comment: Why are you using two versions of jQuery? You are including jQuery 3 times 1.  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") . 2. <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>  3. <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Comment: If you are using the latest version of https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker/ It uses the latest version of jQuery = 2.1 This link from official Example (http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/)

Comment: thank you for pointing out, so i am going try by adding jQuery = 2.1 to Scripts folder and use jQuery 1 time like :@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") in layout

Comment: thank you so much @Dawood Awan, almost done, i just commented other two jquery references in layout and just used jQuery = 2.1.3 in my current View: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>, now it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including jQuery multiple times. Your bundle already included it, so you can remove this line in your layout:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

and these lines from your view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

This line in your Layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

is doing it all for you, because you added those scripts to that bundle.

Including the same script multiple times impacts negatively on performance, but wouldn't normally stop the code from working. However, in this case the different versions of jQuery that you've included are all different versions. I would check what is in your `Scripts` folder and see if it is up to date.

As an aside, it's also considered good practice to put *styles* (e.g. CSS) at the top of the page and *scripts* at the bottom, because that way the browser will load the page properly with styling, and not be slowed down by trying to load scripts halfway through (and if there's a problem with the script, the page still loads).

And as a final aside, you also look like you are a bit confused about the difference between `.min.js` and `.js` (I'm extrapolating from the fact you sometimes use the `min` version and sometimes don't; if you know all this already please excuse me!). The `.min.js` files are a minimised version (variable names as short as possible, comments deleted, whitespace reduced to minimum) that can be sent to the server. You may already have something like this

```
#if DEBUG
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
    // note: overrides compilation debug="true" in Web.config
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

in your Bundle.Config file. If not, it's handy to add because it means that the release version has the best performance (`.min.js` files) but the debug version is more human-readable (normal `.js` files) to help you debug it.

Comment: already i have solved the issue and the same advice was given incomments,i am just accepting it as answer  and thank you for the theory explanations, all the best.